# Xdebug PhpStorm 2016.2

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have followed [this guide](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm) however when I start debuggin the application it debugs every single action and not only the breakpoints that I marked.
the php.ini configuration is the following:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11.dll
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

Do I need another step for it to work..? thanks in advance

Comment: Check that the option "Break at first line in PHP scripts" is disabled. Located at `Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug`

Comment: Awesome, I tried and it worked!! Thanks @pmahomme